# gwt maven compile doesn't generates entry point html file

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have been working on GWT and Maven. I have created a Maven project without any archetype and have configured it with gwt-maven-plugin successfully.

When I compile or run the project, it successfully does everything without any errors or warnings.

However, on `gwt:compile` it can't generate `EntryPointFileName.html` file. So, a 404 error occurs in the browser.

Are there any suggestions or solutions for fixing this?

Comment: Should I share you `pom.xml` or you will share the part of your `pom.xml` specially for compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT (and thus the gwt-maven-plugin) doesn't generate the HTML host page; that's something **you** have to provide. What you're experiencing is the expected behavior.